# Testing module that requires a module from a layer in AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, jestjs, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

So, I am using Layers in my Serverless Framework Node JS project. I add all commonly used npm packages to a layer because I don't want every Lambda function to have huge packages.

The problem is that when running unit tests (locally), it can't find these modules.

Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: How did you upload your zip layer file? please describe your zip structure?

Comment: @AssaelAzran I don't upload the zip file. The serverless framework does all of it for you, you just type the comman 'serverless deploy'. But the layer has nodejs folder where all the code is. My code can see the layers, it's not my problem. The problem is that when running unit tests, it can't see them locally. Other than that, there's a layers folder in the project, where I put all the layers. A layer is a separate project. AWS manages the dependencies between lambdas and layers for you

Comment: Again, the layer works. It is just when running unit tests, it can't see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bar's answer is good, but I also figured that I could install all the dependencies with --save-dev flag and that's it!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Add a package.json file to your project with all of your dependencies
2. Install of the dependencies, so you'll have them locally
3. Use the [Exclude](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging#exclude--include) option in Serverless framework so the final package will not include the node_modules directory:

```
package:
  exclude:
    - node_modules/**
```